# Wordpress like system templating for a SaaS application

Tags: php, codeigniter, joomla, templating

I'm in the process of creating an application that will be deployed as a service ([SaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SaaS))
and I would like to offer the capability to the user of having their own templates and plugin to the system ( with setting up template and plugin market in the future ) something similar to what wordpress and Joomla is doing. The application is done in [Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com) and I'm looking for similar implementation and guide on how to achieve this.

The question is how do I do it, as in how do you design the system with this kind of requirements. Any resource and sample implementation will be much appreciated.

Disclaimer: I'm a newbie to templating world

Comment: So ... what is the concrete question?

Comment: @Marcel please check my edit. Basically what I'm trying to implement this on the existing application.

Comment: You should add some details on what you've looked at already and what you've done (if anything). Have you looked at the CodeIgniter template parser? It may help you with the heavy lifting: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html.